# Mysql selecting values of 4 joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to get first_name, last_name, from_date, and end_date of all employees with title 'Senior Staff' and who work in the Finance department.

employees:

```
# emp_no, birth_date, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date
'10001', '1953-09-02', 'Georgi', 'Facello', 'M', '1986-06-26'
'10002', '1964-06-02', 'Bezalel', 'Simmel', 'F', '1985-11-21'
'10003', '1959-12-03', 'Parto', 'Bamford', 'M', '1986-08-28'
```

employees.departments

```
# dept_no, dept_name
'd002', 'Finance'
'd003', 'Human Resources'
```

employees.dept_manager

```
# emp_no, dept_no, from_date, to_date
'110022', 'd001', '1985-01-01', '1991-10-01'
'110039', 'd001', '1991-10-01', '9999-01-01'
```

employees.titles

```
# emp_no, title, from_date, to_date
'10001', 'Senior Engineer', '1986-06-26', '9999-01-01'
'10002', 'Staff', '1996-08-03', '9999-01-01'
```

Current input

```
SELECT emps.first_name,emps.last_name, t.title, start_date, end_date
FROM employees emps INNER JOIN
     employees.dept_manager dm INNER JOIN
     employees.titles t INNER JOIN
     employees.departments d
     ON t.emp_no = emps.emp_no
WHERE t.title = 'Senior Staff' and d.dept_name = 'Finance' ;
```

This resulted in error 1052: from_date in column is ambiguous

Any suggestions to getting the correct output?

Comment: From_date exists in more than one table - you have to tell mysql which table to use.

Comment: Stefan, Which table contains the `start_date` and `end_date`? Can you clarify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need table `alias` if you have a same column name available with other table.

Secondly your current query has many incorrect syntax's like `JOIN` without `ON` clause. So, the correct version should look like :

```
SELECT emps.first_name,emps.last_name, t.title, t.start_date, t.end_date
------------------------------------------------^-------------^
FROM employees emps INNER JOIN
     employees.dept_manager dm 
     ON emps.emp_no = dm.emp_no INNER JOIN
     employees.titles t 
     ON t.emp_no = emps.emp_no INNER JOIN
     employees.departments d
     ON d.dept_no = dm.dept_no
WHERE t.title = 'Senior Staff' and d.dept_name = 'Finance';
```

Comment: @Yoghesh Sharma Don't we need an `ON` on each `INNER JOIN`? Can you elaborate?